# Unable to instll TestNG form eclipse marketplace getting following error:

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit, testng

I am trying to install the TestNG from the Eclipse(Oxygen and Python) market place, but i am unable to install the applicaint. I am getting following

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: TestNG 7.1.1.202003100345 (org.testng.eclipse.feature.group 7.1.1.202003100345)
  Missing requirement: TestNG Eclipse Support 7.1.1.202003100345 (org.testng.eclipse 7.1.1.202003100345) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.10.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: TestNG 7.1.1.202003100345 (org.testng.eclipse.feature.group 7.1.1.202003100345)
    To: org.testng.eclipse [7.1.1.202003100345]

Answer (score 0):

The message says that the install wants at least version 3.10.0 of the org.eclipse.jdt.launching plug-in.

Eclipse Oxygen only has version 3.9 of this plug-in.

You will need to use a newer version of Eclipse such as the current release 2020-03.